# How to find all empty tiles and instantiate objects in them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, tile

I have created a "PacMan" map in Unity with Tilemaps, but I've never worked with them before, so I want to know, how to find ALL empty tiles on my map in code and spawn objects in them?

[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWBBO.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the web for getting the tile spaces:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class TileTest : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        Tilemap tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();

        BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
        TileBase[] allTiles = tilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);

        for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++) {
                TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
                if (tile != null) {
                    Debug.Log("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " tile:" + tile.name);
                } else {
                    Debug.Log("x:" + x + " y:" + y + " tile: (null)");
                }
            }
        }        
    }   
}
```

I guess you could change it to something like this to get all of the empty spaces: (this script must be attached to the game object with the tile map component)

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class TileTest : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3[] emptyCells;
    void Start () {
        List<Vector3> empty = new List<Vector3>();
        
        Tilemap tilemap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();

        BoundsInt bounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
        TileBase[] allTiles = tilemap.GetTilesBlock(bounds);

        for (int x = 0; x < bounds.size.x; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < bounds.size.y; y++) {
                TileBase tile = allTiles[x + y * bounds.size.x];
                if (tile == null) {
                    empty.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f));
                    Debug.Log("x:" + x + " y:" + y);
                }
            }
        }
        emptyCells = empty.ToArray();
    }   
}
```

This way, you can access the `emptyCells` array, and get the positions to spawn your objects at.

This script will only work if you have it attached to the same game object with the tile map component. If you do not want that, change the first section of the script to this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class TileTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject obj;
    
    Vector3[] emptyCells;
    void Start () {
        List<Vector3> empty = new List<Vector3>();
        
        Tilemap tilemap = obj.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        ...
```

Make sure the `obj` variable is set to the game object with the tile map component.

Let me know if there are any bug

Comment: the first i found is that the objects spawn by size of the cells which are default in Unity, not by the size of cells in tilemap, the second is that i have a problem with size of tilemap, i guess, because the objects spawn beyond the borders of the map

Comment: @Grape If I understand you correctly, they are spawning where they are not supposed to. I guess the problem is that you have changed the size of the tile map cells. Find the size of each cell, and `empty.Add(new Vector3(x, y, 0f) * 1)`, where 1 is the width of the cell.

Comment: yeah, it works, but do you know how to spawn the objects in the center of cell, not in its corner?

 for(int i = 0; i < Tiles.emptyCells.Length; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(Resources.Load("point"), new Vector3(Tiles.emptyCells[i].x, Tiles.emptyCells[i].y, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
        }
(this is my code for spawning objects)

Comment: Yes, you would `empty.Add(new Vector3(x + 0.5, y + 0.5, 0f) * cellLength)` If your cell length was one, you wouldn’t need the last “* cellLength” part. **Replace this line with the one in the for loop in the if statement that looks similar to this**.